# Coerce list in dataframe into binary data type

Tags: r

I want `dat$kirc.mut` to be a dataframe with binary values.
I tried to unlist and coerce into integer. However, my output remains as a list.

```
mut <- as.data.frame(t(apply(dat$kirc.mut, 1, unlist)))
dat$kirc.mut <- as.data.frame(t(apply(mut, 1, as.integer)))
dat$kirc.mut <- t(apply(dat$kirc.mut, 1, unlist))
colnames(dat$kirc.mut) <- colnames(mut)
```

`dat$kirc.mut`

```
> dput(dat$kirc.mut[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(TCGA.A3.3357.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.A3.3367.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.A3.3387.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4698.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4710.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4810.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4811.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4815.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4818.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), TCGA.B0.4821.01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A4GNT", 
"AAAS", "AADAC", "AADACL3", "AADACL4", "AADAT"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A data frame is a special type of list. As you can see in your `dput` output, `class = "data.frame"` means it is a data frame. All the columns appear to to be `integer` class as well (that's what the `L` means in `0L`). I don't think you need to do anything.

Comment: Do you mean you want the columns to be of type `logical()`, e.g. TRUE/FALSE? If so, try something like `df[] <- lapply(df, as.logical)`